# Persistent Warning Message on Google Play Store Listing Despite SDK Update

Tags: android, google-play-services, warnings, policies

I recently encountered an issue related to my app's listing on the Google Play Store. I updated the SDK version to 33 and successfully pushed the updated version to the Play Store. However, even though the updated version is live, I continue to receive a warning message stating: "Your app doesn't adhere to Google Play Developer Program policies. We will take action unless you fix violations before the deadlines."

I want to ensure that my app fully complies with Play Store policies and guidelines. I have reviewed the Developer Program Policies and made necessary adjustments to my app accordingly. Despite this, the warning persists.

I am seeking guidance on how to identify the specific violations that triggered this warning and how to rectify them. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights on how to resolve this matter, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

> buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
> minSdkVersion = 24
> compileSdkVersion = 33
> targetSdkVersion = 33